# Change currency programmatically in order on Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, controllers, currency

I try to change the currency from "RON" to "USD" in a programmatically order but i don't know how. I  also want to add the Store in the order (Purchased from (store)) like in the attached picture

[image] but again, i can't find anything about this.
My code looks like this:

```
//take all product sku
            foreach($product as $key => $value){
                $sku_qty = implode(" ",$value);
                $sqk_qty_array = explode(";",$sku_qty);
                $sku = ($sqk_qty_array[1]);
                $sku_array = explode(".", $sku);
                $products[] = $sku_array[0]."-".$sku_array[0].".".$sku_array[1]."-".$sku_array[2]." ".$sqk_qty_array[2];    
            }
            //take products id by sku
            $products_id = array();
            foreach($products as $key=> $value){
                 //take the sku from array without qty
                $sku_no_qty = explode(" ",$value);
                $sku = $sku_no_qty[0];
                $item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getIdBySku($sku);
                $product_id_qty[] = $id."-".$sku_no_qty[1];
                $products_id []=$id;
            }

            //add order by script
            $email = "test@yahoo.com";
            $productids = $products_id;
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
            // Start New Sales Order Quote
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getId());
            //products count
            $prod_num = count($products_id);
            // Set Sales Order Quote Currency
            $quote->setCurrency($order->AdjustmentAmount->currencyID);
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->loadByEmail($email);
            if ($customer->getId() == "") {
                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                        ->setStore($store)
                        ->setFirstname('Client')
                        ->setLastname('Jolidon')
                        ->setEmail($email)
                        ->setPassword("password");
                $customer->save();
            }

            // Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
            $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
            // Configure Notification
            $quote->setSendCconfirmation(1);
            foreach ($product_id_qty as  $id)
            {   $split = explode("-", $id);
                $id=$split[0]; 
                $qty =$split[1];
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
                $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $qty)));
            }

            // Set Sales Order Billing Address
            $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
                'customer_address_id' => '',
                'prefix' => '',
                'firstname' => 'Client',
                'middlename' => 'Client',
                'lastname' => 'Client',
                'suffix' => '',
                'company' => '',
                'street' => array(
                    '0' => '',
                    '1' => 'Client64'
                ),
                'city' => 'Client',
                'country_id' => 'Client',
                'region' => 'Client',
                'postcode' => 'Client',
                'telephone' => 'Client',
                'fax' => 'Client',
                'vat_id' => '',
                'save_in_address_book' => 1
                    ));

            // Set Sales Order Shipping Address
            $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
                'customer_address_id' => '',
                'prefix' => '',
                'firstname' => 'Client',
                'middlename' => 'Unic',
                'lastname' => 'Client',
                'suffix' => '',
                'company' => '',
                'street' => array(
                    '0' => 'Client',
                    '1' => '45'
                ),
                'city' => 'Client',
                'country_id' => 'Client',
                'region' => 'Client',
                'postcode' => 'Client',
                'telephone' => 'Client',
                'fax' => 'Client',
                'vat_id' => '',
                'save_in_address_book' => 1
                    ));
            if ($shipprice == 0) {
                $shipmethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
            }

            // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
            $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                    ->collectShippingRates()
                    ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
                    ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

            // Set Sales Order Payment
            $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));

            // Collect Totals & Save Quote
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();

            try {
                // Create Order From Quote
                $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
                $service->submitAll();
                $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
            }
            catch (Exception $ex) {
                echo $ex->getMessage();
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

            // Resource Clean-Up
            $quote = $customer = $service = null;

            // Finished
            return  $this->_redirectUrl
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: for change the currency in order i found this answer: Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->setCurrentCurrency(Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load('EUR')); but this code should be put before $quote->collectTotals()->save();

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
 Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->setCurrentCurrency(Mage::ge‌​tModel('directory/cu‌​rrency')->load('EUR'‌​));
```

but this code should be put before `$quote->collectTotals()->save();`